# Change Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I now have a Pandas Dataframe like this:

```
Month Day class 0  1  2  3  4  5  ... 22 23


1     1   A     12 8  9  1  12 3  ... 14 13
1     1   B     0  1  2  3  6  6  ...  3  2
1     2   A     12 10 9  8  7  8  ...  6  7
1     2   B     ... some values
```

since the numeric columns mean `hours"in one day,
I would like to change it to this:

```
Month Day Hours  A   B
1     1      1   12  0
1     1      2   8   1
1     1      3   9   2
...
1     1      23  13  2
1     2      1   12  ..
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df)
   Month  Day class   0   1  2  3   4  5  22  23
0      1    1     A  12   8  9  1  12  3  14  13
1      1    1     B   0   1  2  3   6  6   3   2
2      1    2     A  12  10  9  8   7  8   6   7
3      1    2     B  12  10  9  8   7  8   6   7

df = df.set_index(['Month','Day','class']).stack().unstack(2).reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={'level_2':'Hours'})
df.columns.name=None
print (df)
    Month  Day Hours   A   B
0       1    1     0  12   0
1       1    1     1   8   1
2       1    1     2   9   2
3       1    1     3   1   3
4       1    1     4  12   6
5       1    1     5   3   6
6       1    1    22  14   3
7       1    1    23  13   2
8       1    2     0  12  12
9       1    2     1  10  10
10      1    2     2   9   9
11      1    2     3   8   8
12      1    2     4   7   7
13      1    2     5   8   8
14      1    2    22   6   6
15      1    2    23   7   7
```